# how to add object with fk to table in jparepository

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i had scheme of user parking and detail parking.
user can park many times (one to many)

im trying to add detail parking object to my db, but i dont have idea how to add the fk from the user in the row of the table, its gave me null there.

(ignore from the logic of the model, i just want to understood the logic how can i the object with fk of ther entity)
this is my code:

```
@PostMapping("/parking")
public String saveCarParking(@ModelAttribute("user") parkingUsers parkingUsers) {
    // parkingUsers[id, firstName, lastName, license]
    parkingUsers p = new parkingUsers("jhon", "nash", "248651355");
    parkingUsersService.saveParkingUser(p);

    // parkingDetails[id, entryDate, entryTime, exitDate, exitTime, user_id(FK)]
    parkingDetails d = new parkingDetails(LocalDate.now(), null, LocalDate.now(), null);
    parkingDetailsService.saveParkingUser(d);
    //how i connect parkingDetails object with fk of parkingUsers?
    //it adding now row of parkingDetails but without the fk of user
    
    return "redirect:/parkingList"; 
}
```

parking user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="users")
public class parkingUsers {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "license")   
private String license; 

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parkingUsers", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<parkingDetails> parkingDetails = new ArrayList<parkingDetails>();

public parkingUsers() {
}

public parkingUsers(String firstName, String lastName, String license) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.license = license;
}

//setter gettrs and tostring...
```

entity class of details parking

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="details")
public class parkingDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    
    @Column(name = "entry_date")
    private LocalDate entryDate;

    @Column(name = "entry_time")
    private LocalDateTime entryTime;

    @Column(name = "exit_date")
    private LocalDate exitDate;

    @Column(name = "exit_time")
    private LocalDateTime exitTime;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private parkingUsers parkingUsers;

    public parkingDetails() {}

    public parkingDetails(LocalDate entryDate, LocalDateTime entryTime, LocalDate exitDate, LocalDateTime exitTime) {
        this.entryDate = entryDate;
        this.entryTime = entryTime;
        this.exitDate = exitDate;
        this.exitTime = exitTime;
    }
    
    //test
//  public parkingDetails(LocalDate entryDate, LocalDateTime entryTime, LocalDate exitDate, LocalDateTime exitTime, int user_id ) {
//      this.entryDate = entryDate;
//      this.entryTime = entryTime;
//      this.exitDate = exitDate;
//      this.exitTime = exitTime;
//      this.parkingUsers.setId(user_id);
//  }
    //setter gettrs and tostring...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ParkingDetails entity, you can have a setter for "parkingUsers" variable to set user object.

In your REST api's saveCarParking() method, before calling "parkingDetailsService.saveParkingUser(d);" you can pass the user object to ParkingDetails using setter created in ParkingDetails.

This should work. No need to explicitly extract the user_id from user's object to pass into ParkingDetails.

Adding one more parameter of type ‘parkingUsers‘ in the constructor of ‘ ParkingDetails’ to initialize user in parking class will also work.

(Apart, it is a good practice to start the class name with a capital letter e.g. instead of having class name as **parking**Details, it should be **Parking**Details.)